# mysql config file change on ubuntu not reflected

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I am running an Xubuntu 16.04 machine, and have installed mysql version 5.6. I wanted to change the mysql settings buffer pool size among other things. I tried editing `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`, `/etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf`. Then restarted mysql server. After that, when I login to mysql console and try to print the variables, I still do not see the values I entered in the config files. What am I missing?

**EDIT**

I have put the settings under `[mysqld]` section. Below is the content of the above files:

```
[mysqld]
innodb_buffer_pool_size=4G
innodb_log_buffer_size=512M
innodb_log_file_size=2G
innodb_write_io_threads=16
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0
```

Comment: see if [https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-system-variables.html](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-system-variables.html) helps

Comment: I want the ability to set the mysql settings using a conf file, which obviously is not working. I did try setting variables using sql commands and those worked.